# How to restrict previous and future date but can take five previous date and five future date in html5 date type

Tags: javascript, html, date

I want to restrict users from picking past and future dates but can pick five days of previous or future dates in html5 input type date.

I have used this to hide the previous date:

```js
$(function() { 
  var dtToday = new Date(); 
  var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = dtToday.getDate();
  var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
  if(month < 10) { 
    month = '0' + month.toString();
  } 
  if(day < 10) { 
    day = '0' + day.toString();
  } 
  var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
  $('#delivery_date').attr('min', maxDate); 
});
```

Comment: Hi Shahsbuddin. Have you tried anything? Have you looked at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)?

Comment: @MattEllen I have tried and I can disable past date with javaScript but this doesn't match my condition.

Comment: can you show us the code you have used?

Comment: @MattEllen Sure, I have used this one to hide the previous date

$(function() {
            var dtToday = new Date();
            var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = dtToday.getDate();
            var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
            if(month < 10) {
                month = '0' + month.toString();
            }
            if(day < 10) {
                day = '0' + day.toString();
            }

            var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
            $('#delivery_date').attr('min', maxDate);
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `min` and `max` attributes in the input tag to restrict the range to only five days in the past and five days in the future.
Of course you'll need to get Today's date first using JS and dynamically set the `min` and `max` values.

Here is how you can get today's date using JS:

```
var today = new Date();
```

Here is how you can set the min and max attrubutes:

```
//assuming the date tag has the id date
 var dateTag = document.getElementById("date");

var fiveDaysAgo = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 5)).toISOString().split("T")[0];
var fiveDaysInTheFuture = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 5)).toISOString().split("T")[0];
dateTag.setAttribute("min",fiveDaysAgo);
dateTag.setAttribute("max",fiveDaysInTheFuture);
```

Here is a complete version of it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


  <input type="date" id="date" name="datemax">
</body>
<script>
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
 
  var dateTag = document.getElementById("date");
  var fiveDaysAgo = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 5)).toISOString().split("T")[0];
  var fiveDaysInTheFuture = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 5)).toISOString().split("T")[0];
 dateTag.setAttribute("min",fiveDaysAgo);
 dateTag.setAttribute("max",fiveDaysInTheFuture);
});
</script>
</html>
```